# Java h2 sql results showing 'clob<x>' instead of basic strings

Tags: java, javafx, h2, clob

I'm learning java and practicing by building an app with javafx.

So far so good, except I have this extremely annoying problem. Search results are formatted this way:

{META_KEYWORDS=, META_DESCRIPTION=, CREATED=2015-08-30 14:38:34.284, PUBLISHED=true, PRICE=15.0, DESCRIPTION=**clob6: 'test'**, TITLE=Test, ID=26, SLUG=, EXTENDED_DESCRIPTION=clob7: ''}

clob is clobbering my output :D

Hence `setDescription(row.get("DESCRIPTION").toString());` renders `clob6: 'test'`

I can't see any reason this should happen, except maybe some intermediate interferance from this code I plugged in that generically simplifies ResultSet:

```
public List resultSetToArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    while (rs.next()) {
        HashMap row = new HashMap(columns);
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
            row.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
        }
        list.add(row);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Perhaps the above is irrelevant, but I can't imagine anything else in the pipeline causing this strange text-addition of clob.

Should I be handling clob in any particular way so as to avoid this? I'm making a blogger program and this seemed like the best field to use.

Comment: Well, the columns are, I assume, of type CLOB, not VARCHAR. So that's the type of object you get. So either you change the columns to VARCHAR, or get the data from the CLOB by one of the `java.sql.Clob` methods.

Comment: Either your a genius or I'm extremely ignorant! (Then again, its all relative isn't it!)

That was the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The display seem to indicate that your columns are defined as type `CLOB`.

`CLOB` columns, according to [h2's documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#clob_type), are mapped to the Java `java.sql.Clob` type.

Using the `toString()` for that type is not the same as getting the full string content of the column. `Clob` is an object that intermediates between you and the column to allow you to retrieve the content without holding it all in memory. The `toString()` contract requires returning a short, human-readable representation of the object, and it is usually implemented with logging and debugging in mind. In this case, the object shows some column identification in addition to the content.

So the proper way to get just the content of the `CLOB`, not a "description" of it, is to use one of the methods of the [`java.sql.Clob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html) type. Given that `CLOB` is used for long texts, it may be appropriate to use one of the streams it offers, or if you know the text is short, use `getSubstring`.

But if the data is supposed to be of relatively short texts, and you have control of the table, use [`VARCHAR`](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_type) as the column type, as this type is mapped to `java.lang.String`, and therefore you'll get just the content.

Answer (score -1):

As @RealSkeptic stated, clob had to be dealt with uniquely --

```
            ...


            if(rs.getObject(i) instanceof org.h2.jdbc.JdbcClob){                                       
                Clob clob = rs.getClob(i);
                row.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getClob(i).getSubString(1, (int) clob.length()));
            } else { 
                row.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
            }


            ...
```

So in my `resultSetToArrayList` method I simply had to check for an instance of a clob and get a substring (equal to it's total characters) and that solved it.